# Recharts slow rendering issue

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, use-effect, recharts

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';
import {
  Line,
  LineChart,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
} from 'recharts';

import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:4001";
function App() {
  const [data, updateData] = useState([]);
  const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT, {
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling']
  });
  useEffect(() => {
      socket.on("a", a => { 
        updateData(currentData => [...currentData, a])
       });
  }, []);
  if(data.length>200)
  {
    updateData(data.shift())
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>size of data is :- {data.length}</h1>
     <LineChart width={1000} height={500} data={data}>
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis />
        <Line dataKey="value" />
      </LineChart>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my code I am getting maximum of 200 data per second from socket.io .Code is working fine but as some time passes it start lagging , graph rendering becomes slow .

can any one please tell how can I fix it or optimize it .

Answer (score 0):

There is an anti pattern here, you are calling `data.shift()` which directly modifies the state, which is a no no.

The other issue is your length check is outside the useEffect.

Instead, use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Line, LineChart, XAxis, YAxis } from 'recharts';

import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:4001';
function App() {
  const [data, updateData] = useState([]);
  const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT, {
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('a', (a) => {
      updateData((currentData) => {
        const a = [...currentData, a];
        return a.length <= 200 ? a : a.splice(1);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  const graph = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <LineChart width={1000} height={500} data={data}>
        <XAxis dataKey='name' />
        <YAxis />
        <Line dataKey='value' />
      </LineChart>
    )
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>size of data is :- {data.length}</h1>
      {graph}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: current data in not defined actually In my program current data is just used as a spread operator to push values into array

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I removed the line with currentData outside of the callback.

Comment: your code is working fine but I am having same issue with this one too after 1-2 minute it start lagging

Comment: it's working realtime for 1-2 minute after that there is a gap of 1-2 second and I think it will keep increasing as we move forward

Comment: How often do you want the data to actually update? I'm assuming you need far less than 200 updates a second, this probably depends on how smooth you want the front end to be, but maybe once or twice per second?

Comment: I need it realtime no time gap if that is possible , if it isn't than I am thinking of switching into timely update .

Comment: In updating in a second I am having issues with react lifecycle as like I need to  atleast push data into use state every mili second .

Comment: I actually need 200 update per second if possible

Comment: Interesting, I made an edit to the answer to use the `useMemo` hook, I think as far as optimization available to you, this is it. I'm assuming the bottleneck is from `recharts` so we can try to optimize that with `useMemo`, if you are still having performance issues then I think you may have hit a bottleneck in react or just dom mutations.

Comment: Let me try it will update you with result

Comment: Having the same issue again man  just this time the data lag was less than before

Comment: Is this the chart issue or react js ?

Comment: Could be many things, react, JavaScript, browser, machine. But as far as your code goes I don’t see how you can optimize further.